# Django - Keep overrided User Model (via AUTH_USER_MODEL) in "Authentication and Authorization" group

Tags: django

I am on Django 2.1.2.

What I am trying to do is override the user model as pre suggestion [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)

It work perfectly fine, my problem is about the custom user model show under "Admin > myapp" instead of  "Admin > Authentication and Authorization"

After some search I have tried 2 things.

1) Make use of the **app_label = 'auth'** statement to put it back to app auth, but it break **AUTH_USER_MODEL = myapp.User** in setting.py, coz it is now auth_user.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'auth'
```

2) Move Group to myapp with below statement, so I can put both User and Group together, but it break the user model coz it moved auth_group to myapp_group

```
apps.get_model('auth.Group')._meta.app_label = 'myapp'
```

Any input are welcome

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a proxy model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class ProxyUser(User):
    pass

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'auth'
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = 'user'
```

and add the following to admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User, ProxyUser

admin.site.register(ProxyUser, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks, I find a side effect where your changes will make `admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)` no longer working, nothing will show up in the admin UI, any idea?

Comment: Actually, you have to replace `admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)` for `admin.site.register(ProxyUser, UserAdmin)`.

Comment: `admin.site.register(ProxyUser, UserAdmin)` is fine, what I am asking is about the side effect that `admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)` no longer working.

Comment: Acutally, User is working, it is just not registered in the admin site. With the proxyUser you are just working with the User model through it. The only thing you have to take into account is the premissions table. You will see that there are CRUD permissions in both models. This should be removed manually. Hope it helps.